# Fully Customizable MVC Forum

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, forum

I needed to make a new custom forum for my mom's website( I have recently learned asp.net and mvc and hence plan to build for my mom and my practice).

I tried some forums on CodePlex.com like nearforums etc. But most doesn't let you modify the controllers and models

1. The controllers aren't there.. are they compiled in a .dll?

Then i found POPForums v9, which is completely customizable. and i kinda like it.. so..

1. are there any other mvc forums like POPForums?
2. Does anyone have experience with POPForums .. is it stable?

Comment: To extend some functionality from an existing open source project, you should download the latest version of source code. For example on Nearforums http://nearforums.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

Comment: Try looking at http://themvcforum.codeplex.com

Comment: mvcforum is not free. It is under the GPLv2 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about question #1 , maybe you download a published project.look at the bin directory if exist.generally if it is published there is not any way to change it depending on my experience

about question #2 .really i cant help you
and finally about question #3 depending on my knowledge is it not stable.may be you can find some thing else to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the practice why not just write your own? A simple forum isn't very difficult and you'll learn a lot more from doing it yourself.

Also, if you're looking for source code of a forum to customize, you might want to try looking for an open source forum project.

Comment: popforums is an open source project. The rest say they are open source as well, but still i am not able to see the controller and model folders.. and i need to get it up quick, so i thought i'l use one, and keep making changes. Do u know of any other open source forum projects

Comment: @KshitijBanerjee a quick google search on `open source mvc3 forums` brought up a lot of possibilities. I don't know of any as I have never used one so I can't recommend anything.